# Dynamically Update Web API results using jQuery & AJAX in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-views, django-templates, restful-url

I have this Django app that calls on a web API (RAWG.IO) of over 450,000 games. I am trying to give the users the ability to search for games and get a list, or index of results from that search. The issue is the API is built with multiple pages, so the first call works and list's the first page, but I'm finding it very difficult to get the results from any other page.

I am trying to do it with jQuery/AJAX and a load more games button to smoothly change the current list to another list with the next set of results, but I'm stuck. I'm getting an error.

**Error:** (When the if (url) statement in my JS is left out)

```
lazy_load.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.loadMoreGames [as success] (lazy_load.js:39)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at x (jquery.js:9314)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:9718)
```

***otherwise all the variables become null and undefined and it just skips me to the else statement**

Template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block pagetop %}
{% endblock %}

{% block appcontent %}

<div class="form-container">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
    <input type="submit" id="games" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search Games">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="game-index-container">
  <h1>Games</h1>
  <ul class="game-list">
    {% for game in games %}
    <li class="game-item">
      <h4 class="game-info">{{ game.name }} : {{ game.id }}</h4>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="load-more-games">
  <a class="btn btn-primary more-games" href="javascript:void(0)">Load More Games</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{%  block javascript %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="{% static 'js/lazy_load.js' %}"></script>
{%  endblock %}
```

View:  (for loading the template and getting the first page's results)

```py
def find_games(request):
    games = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.POST.get('search')
        url = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?search=%s' % user_input
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        for game in data['results']:
            items = {'name': game["name"], 'id': game["id"]}
            games.append(items)
    return render(request, 'search/find_game_id.html', {'games': games})
```

and

jQuery/AJAX:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var input;
  var results;
  var next;
  var url = '';
  $('#games').click(function () {
    input = $('#search').val();
    url = `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?search=${input}`;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(url);
        console.log('Total Games: ' + data.count);
        console.log('Number Of Pages: ' + data.count / 20);
        console.log(data.results);
        next = data.next;
        url = next;
      },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error in API Call!');
      },
    });
  });

  $('.more-games').click(function () {
    dict = [];
    url = url;
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'json',
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        results = data.results;
        console.log(results);
        url = data.next;
        if (url) {
          results.forEach((game) => {
            dict.push({
              name: game.name,
              id: game.id,
            });
          });
          $('.game-item').each(function () {
            for (var item in dict) {
              $('.game-info').html(`${item.name} : ${item.id}`);
            }
          });
        } else {
          $('.game-list').html('<li><h4>No More Games To Load!</h4></li>');
        }
      },
    });
    if (url) {
      console.log(url);
    }
  });
});

// function createNode(element) {
//   return document.createElement(element);
// }

// function append(parent, el) {
//   return parent.appendChild(el);
// }

// let ul = document.getElementById('games');
//

// fetch(url)
//   .then((response) => response.json())
//   .then(function (data) {
//     let dict = [];
//     let results = data.results;
//     console.log(results);
//     results.map(function (game) {
//       dict.push({
//         name: game.name,
//         id: game.id,
//       });
//     });
//     let next = data.next;
//     while (next) {
//       url = next;
//       fetch(url)
//         .then((response) => response.json())
//         .then(function (more_data) {
//           let results = more_data.results;
//           results.map(function (more_games) {
//             dict.push({
//               name: more_games.name,
//               id: more_games.id,
//             });
//           });
//           next = more_data.next;
//         });
//     }
//     console.log(dict);
//     return dict.map(function (obj) {
//       let li = createNode('li'),
//         h4 = createNode('h4');
//       h4.innerHTML = `${obj.name} : ${obj.id}`;
//       append(li, h4);
//       append(ul, li);
//     });
//   })
//   .catch(function (error) {
//     console.log(error);
//   });
```

Comment: Hi you have written `url = next;` and then inside again in `$('.more-games').click(function () {..` you have `url=url`  not sure why ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Swati It’s a remnant of me trying to figure out how to have the variables keep their values from the original Ajax call. Since url is a global variable I could just erase it, but shouldn’t it not make a difference as it should just be the value of data.next regardless? The main issue is once the form is submitted the variables are loosing their values and returning null or undefined. If I put a `onsubmit=“return false”` in the form tag I can see the values in the console, but that does me no good.

Comment: why you are submitting form and using ajax both ?

Comment: @Swati I was using the Django view to get the results for the first page, but I have since updated the JS to only use ajax to submit the form.

Comment: Hi you store that `next url` somewhere in your dom hidden so whenever user click of load more games you can get the value from there and do further process.. other way would be using localstorage .

Comment: I was missing the event.preventDefault() which stops the form submission from reloading the page and resetting all my variables. Thanks for your help though!